# How to fix permission denied when trying to download Google Play app reports?

Tags: google-api, google-play

I have followed [Googles descriptions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en#zippy=%2Csee-an-example-python%2Creviews%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-client-library-service-account) to the letter, but when I try to download a report from the bucket using the service account I get an error saying `.... does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.`.

From what I can tell the `pubsite_prod_rev_xxx` bucket is managed by Google Play and adding the service account should (at least in theory) grant access to it.

Has anyone been able to get this working?

[image: descriptions]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess permissions are only updated when a new report is generated because it works now. So if you have this problem you might just have to wait a day.

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself. They should really put this information *prominently* in the documentation, so that developers don't waste hours of their time!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, in one of my cases it took more than a day for permissions to be applied. I found out later that no files were created on bucket that day, so although I haven't found any source to Kimble's answer, that may indeed be the reason.