403 forbidden when accessing play store stats created by play console in cloud storage
I'm trying following this doc https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?visit_id=638657507285803777-2285004877&p=stats_export&rd=1#export&zippy=%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-command-line-tool
to download play store analytics using a python script.
I noticed that the bucket is not listed in my buckets, because it was created by Google automaticall. When i paste the url of the bucket, I can access it.
I created a service role, attached all bucket roles on it, but got :

"errorMessage": "403 GET
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false:
id-gara-lambda-playstore-analy@gara-android-store.iam.gserviceaccount.com
does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage
bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may
not exist).",   "errorType": "Forbidden",

The gmail user I used to create this service role is full admin on my play store console.
I don't know what to do.
The service role is created under my organisation. But I don't know which organization the buckets created by Google belongs to.
Under permissions, I even can't add the permissions

What could I do to tell Google to give to the service account an access to this bucket for read ?
Thank you.

I'm unfamiliar with Play Console and downloading the analytics. However (!) I suspect that Cloud Storage bucket is owned by Google but granted permission(s) to the Play Console users that you define. Are you able to add the Service Account's email address (id-gara-lambda-playstore-analy@gara-android-store.iam.gserviceaccount.com) to your Play Console as a "user"? That should update the Bucket's I AM permissions and enable your code (authenticated as that Service Account) to access the Bucket's objects.

It seems like the issue is regarding the IAM permissions assigned to your service account. Have you tried assigning a role that includes the storage.buckets.get permission like Storage Object Viewer or Storage Admin? You can check the IAM roles in this documentation.

@DazWilkin YES bucket is owned by Google. But ooh, you are maybe right, it's this email, i should add to play store, not the gmail email i use to connect. I'll try. TY

Don't remove your Gmail email because you will be unable to access. You should be able to add the Service Account's email address as well.

@DazWilkin still have the same error, even if the service account is added. Storage Object Viewer and Storage Admin is added to this service account.

The IAM permissions need to be applied to the Bucket or its containing Project but you (likely) don't have the permission to apply these permissions on these objects as they're Google-owned. I was assuming the permissions would be effected by the Play Console when you added the Service Account email address. Are you using Application Default Credentials to authenticate your Python code? If so, are you able to authenticate using your user credentials

In my python app I generated a json credentials. This json credentials is attached to the service account

Permissions can take 24h to update also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734148/how-to-fix-permission-denied-when-trying-to-download-google-play-app-reports
